# monkeyrunner can't be started up with an error

Tags: sdk, monkeyrunner

I met an error of

> SWT folder '..\framework\x86_64' does not exist. Please set
>   ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your
>   platform.

when i run the monkeyrunner in the first time.By the way, the sdk is installed with the androidStudio 3.0.

I tried to check my jdk and python, and they are ok.

Comment: And the uiautomatorviewer is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform, use following command:

`setx -m ANDROID_SWT "C:\Users\pang\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64"`

Keep in mind that the path has to reflect your actual path.