# How do I properly set up java paths and other system variables to start monkeyrunner?

Tags: java, android, monkeyrunner

When I first attempted to run monekyrunner.bet I got some error about java not being found. At that moment java.exe was at `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe` which came with the latest android studio installation (`Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1; Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 amd64`). I added this path to JAVA_HOME system variable, but I kept getting the same error.

```
java version:  
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866, mixed mode)
```

I then downloaded jdk-19 from `https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-windows` as recommended in the moneyrunner error text. Now I have another java.exe at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe` and I set `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\` in JAVA_HOME.

```
java version:  
java 19.0.1 2022-10-18  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)
```

After this I started getting some error about SWT folder not existing. Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307481/monkeyrunner-cant-be-started-up-with-an-error), I added an ANDROID_SWT system variable, which I have set to `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64\`.

After this I got some error about `monkeyrunner-26.0.0-dev.jar`. Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47548474/error-when-run-monkeyrunner), I modified the monkeyrunner bat file as explained in the post, but now I am getting
this error:

```
-Djava.ext.dirs=.;C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64"
-Dcom.android.monkeyrunner.bindir=..\framework -jar .\..\lib\monkeyrunner-26.0.0-dev.jar  is not supported.  Use
-classpath instead.   
 Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.   
 Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

.

```
System variables:  
ANDROID_SWT : C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64\  
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\
```

Is there a step by step guide on how exactly to start monkeyrunner? I want to send input events through monkeyrunner, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959654).

Answer (score 0):

monkeyrunner is unmaintained it's working with java versions 1.8 and older